# clear cache of browser by command line

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, command-line, browser-cache

I am working in media domain. I need to check every change in all leading browsers i.e. IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

To clear cache, every time i need to use Ctrl + Shift + del.

Is there any another way to clear the cache of every web browser using command line?

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to clear all trash & caches (without other private data in browsers) by a command line. This is a command line batch script that takes care of all trash (as of April 2014):

```
erase "%TEMP%\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%TEMP%\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"

erase "%TMP%\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%TMP%\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"

erase "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\TEMP\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\TEMP\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"

erase "%SystemRoot%\TEMP\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%SystemRoot%\TEMP\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"


@rem Clear IE cache -  (Deletes Temporary Internet Files Only)
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
erase "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"

@rem Clear Google Chrome cache
erase "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"


@rem Clear Firefox cache
erase "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%i in ("%LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"

pause
```

I am pretty sure it will run for some time when you first run it :)
Enjoy!

Comment: It really looks like the Firefox part will delete all profile data (bookmarks, home page, add-ons, ...) Instead of just the cache. Also if for some reason %TMP% or %TEMP% are not set, you could end up emptying the current drive...

Comment: updates for october 2015 ? delete Profile date Firefox ?

Comment: what is erase? did you mean echo erase?

Answer (score 15):

**You can run Rundll32.exe for IE Options control panel applet and achieve following tasks.**

---

*Deletes ALL History* - `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255`

*Deletes History Only* - `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1`

*Deletes Cookies Only* - `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2`

*Deletes Temporary Internet Files Only* - `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8`

*Deletes Form Data Only* - `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16`

*Deletes Password History Only* - `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32`

Comment: This is valid for IE7+.
IE6 does not have a ClearMyTracksByProcess entry point in InetCpl.cpl.

Comment: IE6 is dead completely

Comment: you should be aware of the "low integrity - protected mode"; see http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/clear-ie-cache-command-line-rundll32/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, really cool and helpful! Works great for clearing a distant computer's IE cache with PSEXEC. Cheers

Comment: I am using the Cache clear in Bat file, <RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351>. i am using this code in a RPA Automation solution, the issue is that is opening up a Pop-Up, which we are not able to handle that Pop-Up.. so is there any solution that runs in the background to clean the cache memory

Comment: Will this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec