# Delete Site Data through command line in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-devtools

Even after searching on Google a lot I am not able to find the solution to my problem. I am looking for an alternative to the following button through command line which delete service worker, cache and all other stored data for a specific website or web application.

In Google Chrome Dev Tools --> Goto Application --> Clear storage --> Clear Site Data

[image: Delete Site data in Chrome Dev Tools]

Are there any specific file/folder in this location to delete? Or just simply, using a switch with some parameters while opening Chrome can do this?

I already visited this link but it suggests to clear all the data instead for a specific website.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621969/clear-cache-of-browser-by-command-line

Kindly show me the path !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevTools functions aren't available through the command line. These are features for developers to test applications with and develop them further. They aren't for automating tasks external to development purposes.