# Programmatically clear IE cache from python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I am seeing 'command line' options for clearing the IE cache from a command line, but cannot figure out how to do this programmatically from python, or even from an MS Dos prompt for that matter. Here's what I found from [StackOverflow: clear cache of browser by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621969/clear-cache-of-browser-by-command-line):

*Deletes ALL History* - RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

*Deletes History Only* - RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

*Deletes Cookies Only* - RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

*Deletes Temporary Internet Files Only* - RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

*Deletes Form Data Only* - RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

*Deletes Password History Only* - RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32

So my question is, how can I convert the above 'commands' into something I can run directly from python using subprocess, for example, that will clear the IE cache.

Comment: Are you able to run it from CLI? If you do - look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html and see how to invoke it from python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Just comment out whatever command you don't want/need.

```
import subprocess

commands = (
            "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255", # Deletes ALL History 
            "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1",   # Deletes History Only
            "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2",   # Deletes Cookies Only
            "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8",   # Deletes Temporary Internet Files Only
            "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16",  # Deletes Form Data Only 
            "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32",  # Deletes Password History Only
            )

for command in commands:
    with subprocess.Popen(command) as p:
        p.wait()
        print(f"{p.returncode} - {command}")
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I think I was not properly invoking subcommand...

Comment: @DavidMiller, from your last comment. It looks like your issue was solved with the suggestion given by Gordon. I suggest you to mark Gordon's answer as an accepted answer. It can help other users in similar kind of issue in future. Thanks for your understanding.